# How to prove that text is linearly separable?

Tags: svm, text-mining, kernel-trick, libsvm, natural-language

I sentiment analisys task, for this I used SVM with an rbf kernel and a linear one. The results for the linear kernel were better than the rbf, from [this](https://charlesmartin14.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/kernels_part_1/) I know that text is linearly separable, but how can I provide a formal proof of this?.

Answer (score 3):

You can't formally prove this, unless you happen to be able to fit a hard margin SVM on your data (unlikely). However, intuitively, text representations are high dimensional (bag of words, n-grams, ...). The higher the dimensionality, the easier it is to linearly separate data, as the [VC dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension) of a linear classifier in $d$ dimensions is $d+1$ (e.g. see [these slides](http://cs.nyu.edu/~dsontag/courses/ml13/slides/lecture10.pdf)). The VC dimension is the largest amount of points that a classifier can [shatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension#Shattering) (separate).

Additionally, you should be aware that the linear kernel is equivalent to a degenerate RBF kernel, which means that with a properly tuned RBF kernel you should be getting at least the same accuracy as a linear kernel. That said, using an RBF kernel on such data is a waste of time and effort, because it typically offers very little improvement and tremendously increases computational cost.

Comment: Sure, I tried with the Linear kernel and my metrics increasead amazingly.... Do you think is wrong to use the RBF kernel for text, in particular opinions?.

Comment: @ml_guy it is not wrong per se, as the RBF kernel *can* yield at least comparable performance. However, training a model with RBF kernel takes a lot more time *and* you would have to tune the kernel bandwidth, which takes orders of magnitude more time than training a linear model. Hence, using an RBF kernel on high dimensional data is usually a waste of computational effort. You can see a similar reasoning in [A practical guide for SVM classification](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) (appendix C).